# Communicate between Activity and ViewPager Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager

Like in the image below, I have an `Activity` with a `ViewPager` (with `TabLayout`) inside.
Now I want to refresh for example the text of an `TextView` in a `ViewPager` `Fragment`. How can I do this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GknIX.jpg
[Sorry for the image link, but I don't have enough reputations yet.]

I already tried something like this:

```
//In Activity
View root = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null);
TextView textView = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
textView.setText("test");
```

But I get a `NullPointerException` for the textView.

Edit 1:
I only need to access the components inside one Fragment, so I am not using an array inside the Adapter.
I changed my `ViewPagerAdapter` to this:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public HomeFragment fragment;

    ...

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return fragment = new HomeFragment();
            case 1:
                ...
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

But I still get a `NullPointerException` here:

```
final Fragment root = viewPagerAdapter.fragment;
Log.d("testtest", String.valueOf(root == null));
```

Comment: Did you want to change the fragment's text view value from an activity?

Comment: @NazmulHasanMasum yep, you understood me right

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refresh data in ViewPager Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503779/refresh-data-in-viewpager-fragment)

Comment: Perhaps you can tell me, what exactly happens in the activity that updates the textview inside the viewpager?

Answer (score 1):

Write this code in your activity where you want to change fragment value. Your fragment id is e.g. my_fragment

```
Fragment frag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.my_fragment)
((TextView) frag.getView().findViewById(R.id.text_view)).setText(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Adapter:

```
private class YourAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener
{
    Fragment screens[];
    public CheckinHistoryAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        screens = new Fragment[3];
        screens[0] = new CoachFragment();
        screens[1] = new LogingFragment();
        screens[2] = new HistoryFragment();
    }

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    if(index <= screens.length)
    {
        return screens[index];
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return screens.length;
}

}
```

Use it like this

```
mViewPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
```

You can access fragment object with getItem method.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a reference to one Fragment, then just use the `position` parameter passed into `instantiateItem()`, and only assign your Fragment reference for the desired position:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public HomeFragment fragment;

    //...

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new HomeFragment(); //modified
            case 1:
                ...
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
      Fragment createdFragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
      if (position == 0) {
        fragment = (HomeFragment) createdFragment;
      }
      return createdFragment;
    }
}
```

Comment: I still get a `NullPointerException`: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.view.View de.ccb.weighttracker.fragment.HomeFragment.rootView on a null object reference`

Comment: I may be trying to communicate to the ViewPager Fragments View, when it isn't fully setup. When is the first time to communicate without the possibility that the Fragment is null?

Comment: At the moment I am communicating in the `onCreate()` of my Activity. I am 100% sure, that this is my problem. I tested it.

Comment: Everything correct there, please trust me and just answer the question

Comment: "When is the first time to communicate without the possibility that the Fragment is null?"

Comment: @responseinline You are correct, it won't work in `onCreate()`, as the FragmentPagerAdapter isn't fully set up yet.  The method in this answer is primarily used for communicating with ViewPager Fragments after onCreate().  Why exactly do you need to refresh a TextView from the onCreate() function of the Activity?  You can just do it in `onCreateView()` of the Fragment.....