# Trying to update my tab content

Tags: android, tabs, updates

i´m using tablayout and i want to update the tab content when user clicks on the tab. basicly i want to do what the tab does when it is created (check what it is in database and put it on my listview).

here is my MainActivity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
        // Declaring Your View and Variables
        Toolbar toolbar;
        ViewPager viewPager;
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
        TabLayout tabLayout;
        CharSequence Titles[]={"Participantes","Torneio","Classificação"};
        int Numboftabs =3;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
            tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);


            // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
            adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);
            // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTextIcons));
            tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }


                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            viewPager = null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            if (id == R.id.action_info) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Contacto: Juniortalisson16@gmail.com", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }


    }
```

Here is my ViewPageradapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    CharSequence Titles[]; // This will Store the Titles of the Tabs which are Going to be passed when ViewPagerAdapter is created
    int NumbOfTabs; // Store the number of tabs, this will also be passed when the ViewPagerAdapter is created


    // Build a Constructor and assign the passed Values to appropriate values in the class
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabsumb) {
        super(fm);

        this.Titles = mTitles;
        this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
        FragmentManager manager = ((Fragment) object).getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
        trans.remove((Fragment) object);
        trans.commit();
    }

    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    //This method return the fragment for the every position in the View Pager
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch(position) {// if the position is 0 we are returning the First tab
            case 0:
            Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
            return tab1;
            case 1:
            Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
            return tab2;
            case 2:
            Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();
            return tab3;
            default:
                return null;
        }


    }

    // This method return the titles for the Tabs in the Tab Strip

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return Titles[position];
    }

    // This method return the Number of tabs for the tabs Strip

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NumbOfTabs;
    }
}
```

i tried to use the getItemPosition but it didn´t work, my app crash when i select an tab.

Any ideias? please

Comment: Just make a public method in your Fragment that updates the adapter data, see here: [Refresh data in ViewPager Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503779/refresh-data-in-viewpager-fragment)

Comment: If I do understand your code Tab1, Tab2 and Tab3 are fragments. If so you can use the onResume method in each of those fragments to "refresh" the contents.

Comment: @geraldo that won't work with a ViewPager, as it keeps the Fragments on either side of the current one alive.

Comment: @Daniel, but suppose he is filling his ListViews with a CursorLoader then he can call restartLoader in the onResume, and adapter.swapCursor in the onLoadFinished which will refresh the contents of his ListView.

Comment: @geraldo for example, say you have two tabs.  You can swipe back and forth between tabs, and onResume() will never be called, since the FragmentPagerAdapter is keeping both Fragments alive.

Comment: yeah, i tried onResume() Geraldo Freitas, and has Daniel said it didn´t work out, i will try to use a public method Daniel. thanks