# Calling Fragment onPageSelected method

Tags: android, android-fragments

How do I call a fragment onpageselected method? I have 20 tabs. In every tab I call the same fragment. However, when I click different tab I want it to reload itself. How can I do that? Thanks.

I want to make an app like Google Play News.

> MyViewPagerAdapter

```
 ViewPager viewPager = materialViewPager.getViewPager();
    viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position % 21) {
                case 0:
                    return NewsContentFragment.newInstance();
                case 1:
                    return NewsContentFragment.newInstance();
                case2:
                continues in the same way to 21...
```

Comment: Hard to tell, but this will probably help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36504458/4409409

Comment: Thanks but do I have to create 20 fragments? This is so weird no more solution :(

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're asking, can you be more specific?

Comment: You know Google Play News app right? It has over 15-20 tabs and they use only one Fragment for 20 tabs. I am working on a project like Google's. I added 20 tabs to viewpager. I also use one Fragment and one RecyclerView for these categories. Think about it, for instance I am on 'kid category'. Program shows me news related to kids. When I click 'fashion category'  program shows me news related to fashion. However the app needs to do these in only one Fragment. I mean fragment needs to update itself when tabs are changed. How do I do this? What function should I do this? onPageSelected or?

Comment: It sounds like the approach in the answer I linked to would work. You have one Fragment class, and then 20 Fragment references in your FragmentPagerAdapter, correct?  If you post your current FragmentPagerAdapter code it would be much easier to help.....

Comment: @DanielNugent I have added my codes to the question. Please check them out. I am looking forward to your comment :)

Comment: Ok, looks good.  You can definitely use the technique from the linked answer, just add the `instantiateItem()` override in the FragmentPagerAdapter, add the `fragments` array, and add the ViewPager OnPageChangedListener.

Comment: If you don't mind can you please transcribe for my project?