# ViewPager and updating Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-maps-v2

In my app's activity, I have a ViewPager implementation which loads a Map fragment (FragmentA) on launch and then there are 2 other fragments showing content based on the latitude and longitude selected in FragmentA.

I am unable to get the behavior where upon launch, the latitude/longitude from FragmentA, should be provided to the 2 other fragments and continue to provide whenever user clicks on the map in FragmentA.

Here are the approaches I tried:

1. using interface to communicate between fragment -> activity -> fragment (*sticking with this approach*)
2. using bundle to pass information between fragments when the fragments are getting initialized

However, neither of these approaches have worked for me.

**MyActivity.java**//update to show Daniel's suggestion

```
public class MyDemoActivity extends FragmentActivity
                implements FragmentA.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
                    FragmentB.OnFragmentInteractionListener, IUserLatLong  {

    private MyPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_in_pager_demo);

        ViewPager mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getApplicationContext());
        mPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        //always start w/ Maps View, FragmentA
        mPager.setCurrentItem(1);

        //
        mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            //do something
           }

           @Override
           public void onPageSelected(int position) {
             // do this instead of calling, notifyDataSetChanged()
            Fragment frag = pagerAdapter.fragments[position];
            if (frag != null && frag instanceof FragmentB) {
                Log.i(TAG, "::FragmentB:: Fetching data from Activity");
                //here is my confusion, calling FragmentB with latlong from FragmentA
                ((FragmentB) frag).setNewLatLong(newUserLatLong);
            }
           }

           @Override
           public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
             //do something
           }
       });
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {
        //do something
    }

    @Override
    public void makeUseOfNewLocation(UserLatLong userLatLong) {
       newUserLatLong = userLatLong;
       Log.i(TAG, "LatLong from FragmentA is: " + newUserLatLong.getLat()
                + " and long is: " + newUserLatLong.getLng());
    }

/**
 * Used for fetching data from activity
 * @return
 */
public UserLatLong getLLFromActivity() {
      if(newUserLatLong == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "LatLong from FragmentA came up empty");
      } else {

        Log.i(TAG, "LatLong from FragmentA IS NOT empty: " + newUserLatLong.getLat()
                + " and long is: " + newUserLatLong.getLng());
      }
      return newUserLatLong;
    }

}
```

**MyPagerAdapter.java**

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;
    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
       super(fm);
       this.context = context; 
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    // not sure if this is really helping
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        // POSITION_NONE makes it possible to reload the PagerAdapter
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                //uses location from FragmentA to get data
                return new FragmentB();
            case 1:
                //loads map and gets location
                return new FragmentA();
            case 2:
                //uses location from FragmentA to get data
                return new FragmentC();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

   //This populates your Fragment reference array:
   @Override
   public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
       Fragment createdFragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
       fragments[position]  = createdFragment;
       Log.i(TAG, "::instantiateItem:: " + position + " " + createdFragment.toString());
       return createdFragment;
    }

}
```

**FragmentA.java** /**left out most of map specific code,
but I am interested in getting latitude/longitude whenever `onConnected()` or `onMapClick()` gets called*/

```
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
     Log.i(TAG, "In onConnected(), Google API client is:: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());

     if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
         try {
                // Get last known recent location.
                mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

                if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
                    // Print current location if not null
                    final LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(),
                                                        mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());

                    //wrap LatLng into UserLatLong
                    userLatLong.setLat(latLng.latitude);
                    userLatLong.setLng(latLng.longitude);
//updating the value in the interface
                    mLLCallback.makeUseOfNewLocation(userLatLong);

                    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 20);
                    mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
                    Log.i(TAG, "::Google::My current location set::");

                    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng1) {
                            mMap.clear(); //removes the previous marker
                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng1));

                //updating the value in the interface
                mLLCallback.makeUseOfNewLocation(userLatLong);
                            float x = (float) latLng1.latitude;
                            float y = (float) latLng1.longitude;
                            Log.d(TAG, "Map clicked w/ lat: " + x + " and long: " + y);

                            //wrap LatLng into UserLatLong
                            userLatLong.setLat(latLng1.latitude);
                            userLatLong.setLng(latLng1.longitude);

                        }
                    });

                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

                    //for zooming automatically to the location of the marker
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(latLng).zoom(12).build();
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                    //TODO: Constrain the camera target to bounds defined by API
                    mMap.setMinZoomPreference(Constants.DEFAULT_MIN_ZOOM);
                    mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(Constants.DEFAULT_MAX_ZOOM);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Current location is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (SecurityException se1) {
                Log.e(TAG, "SecurityException1: " + se1.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Google API client is null!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

**FragmentB** /**in this fragment, I want to refresh content based on latitude/longitude from `FragmentA`*/

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
    /**
     * Required empty public constructor
     */
    public FragmentB() {
    }


/**the getArguments() is always null*/
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    currLatLong = getNewLatLong();
    }

    /**I want latitude/longitude from FragmentA before onCreateView gets called*/ 
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        LayoutInflater inflater1 = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
       currLatLong = getNewLatLong();
        //fetch my list based on LatLong
        handleDataFetch(currLatLong);

        return view;
    }

    //
    private void handleDataFetch(UserLatLong newLatLong) {
        final UserLatLong latLong = newLatLong;
        final APIEndpointI apiEndpointI = APIRequests.getClient().create(APIEndpointI.class);

        String userId = "XXXX-XXX-XXXXXXX";

        currLatLong = new UserLatLong(newLat.doubleValue(), newLong.doubleValue());
        if (currLatLong != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Finally! Lat is: " + currLatLong.getLat() +
                    " and Long is:" + currLatLong.getLng());
            /**using retrofit*/
            Call<MyResp> call = apiEndpointI.getMyList(userId, currLatLong);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<MyResp>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<MyResp> call, Response<MyResp> response) {


                    Log.i(TAG, "Count: " + response.body().getBundles().size());
                    Resources res = getContext().getResources();
                    String cntString = String.format(res.getString(R.string.count), response.body().getBundles().size());
                    tv1.setText(cntString);

                    //Initialize with empty data
                    mGridData = new ArrayList<>();
                    mGridAdapter = new ProfilePicAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.grid_item_layout, mGridData);
                    mGridView.setAdapter(mGridAdapter);

                   }    
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<MyResp> call, Throwable t) {
                    //do something here
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed to get response for GetMyList(): " + t.getMessage());
                }
            });
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "In onCreateView(), lat long are empty");
        }
    }


   //called from activity to pass the latest latlong
   public void setNewLatLong(UserLatLong userLatLong) {
      currLatLong = userLatLong;
   }

   //called from activity to pass the latest latlong
   private UserLatLong getNewLatLong() {
      return currLatLong;
   }

}
```

Comment: In the above implementation, the fragment that I swipe to `FragmentB` doesn't get updated w/ the new location from `FragmentA` instead a different fragment, `FragmentC` gets the updated location. I am not sure why that is happening. I am using approach # 1, using interface to communicate between fragments.

Comment: Made some progress - updated **MyActivity** with `addOnPageChangeListener` but now Map fragment, **FragmentA** also gets refreshed which creates 2 problems: #1 selected map location is only available to the view that I swipe to and, if I swipe again, I return to Map fragment **FragmentA** which gets created again and hence the newly selected fragment doesn't get the previously selected location #2 because of `pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` all the fragments get refreshed and the refresh is particularly visually noticeable on the Map fragment.

Comment: No need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the PagerAdapter.  Just keep a reference to the ViewPager Fragments, store the current data in the Activity, and give the latest data to the relevant Fragment each time it loads.  See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503779/refresh-data-in-viewpager-fragment

Comment: @DanielNugent thank you. You are kind enough to post lot of answers and you responded to my question! Based on your response, I am unsure of passing data from activity to `FragmentB`/`FragmentC`.

Current impl: defined an interface `IUserLatLong` with only `makeUseOfNewLocation(userLatLong)`. `FragmentA` implements, gets location data and passes to this method, and the Activity too implements this interface so, in `onCreateView` of `FragmentB`/`FragmentC` they just call a public method `getLLFromActivity()` in Activity to get LatLong. 

How do I go about data transfer in this new approach?

Comment: The reason is that neither `FragmentB.newInstance(userLatLong)` or calling `bundle` have worked for me .

Comment: It looks good for the most part.  Looks like you should also call ``((FragmentB) frag).handleDataFetch(newUserLatLong);`` after the call to `((FragmentB) frag).setNewLatLong(newUserLatLong);`, but only if the location has changed.

Comment: That is not helping as I don't see `FragmentB`'s `onCreateView()` being called because `handleDataFetch(newUserLatLong)` is called from `onCreateView()`.

Comment: I stand correted. `FragmentB`/`FragmentC` are getting the updated location and hence updated content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like all you need to complete [the implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36504458/4409409) is to call `handleDataFetch()` from the `setNewLatLong()` method if it is a new location.

This is needed since `onCreateView()` won't be called due to the Fragment being in a ViewPager, so the best way to get the updated location info to FragmentB when it is displayed is to just use a public method called from the `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` in the Activity, as you are doing here.

Just be sure that your `equals()` method override is implemented correctly in the `UserLatLong` class, and add this to the `setNewLatLong()` method:

```
   //called from activity to pass the latest latlong
   public void setNewLatLong(UserLatLong userLatLong) {
      //Added:
      if (!currLatLong.equals(userLatLong)) {
          handleDataFetch(userLatLong);
      }
      currLatLong = userLatLong;
   }
```