# Pass data to fragment and refresh it from another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 Tab fragments and a menu list fragment:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FlowingDrawer mDrawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("TAB1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("TAB2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("TAB3"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

PagerAdapter:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                TabFragment1 tab1 = new TabFragment1();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                TabFragment2 tab2 = new TabFragment2();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                TabFragment3 tab3 = new TabFragment3();
                return tab3;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

Here is one of the tab fragments, what I want is to change the "cat" string in this class and reload the tab from another fragment, the menu fragment below:

```
public class TabFragment2 extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public AVLoadingIndicatorView indicatorView;
    List<AdModel> Ads;
    AdsAdapter adapter;
    AdsApi api;
    int page = 1;
    String TAG = "TabFragment2";
    String cat = "0";


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_2, container, false);
        final FragmentActivity c = getActivity();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        indicatorView= (AVLoadingIndicatorView) c.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        Ads = new ArrayList<>();


        adapter = new AdsAdapter(c, Ads);
        adapter.setLoadMoreListener(new AdsAdapter.OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        page++;
                        loadMore(page, cat);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        api = ServiceGenerator.createService(AdsApi.class);
        load(1, cat);

        return rootView;
    }
```

MenuList Fragment, here is where I need to reload the tab from, and pass the the "cat" value:

```
public class MenuListFragment extends Fragment {

    private ImageView ivMenuUserProfilePhoto;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container,
                false);
        ivMenuUserProfilePhoto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivMenuUserProfilePhoto);
        NavigationView vNavigation = (NavigationView) view.findViewById(R.id.vNavigation);
        vNavigation.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),menuItem.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

// here is where I need to reload the tab from, and pass the the "cat" value


                return false;
            }
        }) ;
        setupHeader();
        return  view ;
    }

    private void setupHeader() {
        int avatarSize = 20;
        String profilePhoto = "";

    }

}
```

How can I pass values from a fragment to another, and reload it?

---

**EDIT:**
Answered by checking: [Refresh data in ViewPager Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503779/refresh-data-in-viewpager-fragment)

Comment: Send the updated data to the activity, and when the other fragment is shown, update it.  see here for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503779/refresh-data-in-viewpager-fragment

Comment: Use bus events.

Comment: @DanielNugent thank you very much, it worked.